# how to centre a css menu for iPhones and all web browsers

Tags: css, menu

I use a css menu for my website and the menu shifts around when using a MacBook, iPad of different iPhones so that sometimes they are not centred on the screen. At the moment, the menu does wrap around to form two layers of menus if the screen is smaller, but they are not centred on the screen. I am a little confused on my current code what to alter to make sure the menu items are always centred no matter what screen it is viewed on. Any help would be appreciated as I am not a professional coder.

Here I have six menus, three with submenus and three with direct page links.

```
<!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section -->
<ul  id="css3menu0"  class="topmenu">
    <li  class="topfirst"><a  href="#"  style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;"><span>Menu1</span></a>
        <ul  style="width: 145px;">
              <li><a  href="subpage1a.html">subMenu1a </a></li>
              <li><a  href="subpage1b.html">subMenu1b </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li  class="topmenu"><a  href="#"  style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;"><span>Menu2</span></a>
            <ul  style="width: 145px;">
              <li><a  href="subpage2a.html"> subMenu2a</a></li>
              <li><a  href="subpage2b.html"> subMenu2b</a></li>
              <li><a  href="subpage2c.html"> subMenu2c</a></li>
              <li><a  href="subpage2d.html"> subMenu2d</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li  class="topmenu"><a  href="page3.html"  style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;">Menu3</a></li>
          <li  class="topmenu"><a  href="#"  style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;"><span>Menu4</span></a>
          <ul  style="width: 145px;">
              <li><a  href="subpage4a.html"> subMenu4a</a></li>
              <li><a  href="subpage4b.html"> subMenu4b</li>
              <li><a  href="subpage4c.html"> subMenu4c</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li  class="topmenu"><a  target="_blank"  href="https://www.instagram.com/xxx/" style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;">Instagram</a></li>
     <li  class="toplast"><a  href="page6.html"  style="width: 130px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px;">Menu6</a></li>
</ul>
<p  class="_css3m"><a  href="http://css3menu.com/">Creating CSS Menu Css3Menu.com</a></p>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->
```

at the moment the menu positioning shifts according to the screen width, which one would expect, and on smaller screens (eg iPhones) the menu wraps to two rows. The problem is that they are not centring on the screen.

Comment: you put up a preview image  of what you have now

Comment: how can I add two images? I tried Ctrl-G (on a Mac) and Cmd-G, but no good

Answer (score 0):

Create a container and:

```
.container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response. Please forgive my ignorance, but do I place the container within the code posted or at the top of my html page? Do I also need to close the container?